# Function to count all rows with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the `COUNTIFS` statement to count all rows where values in 4 different columns equal "something", while excluding rows where the values in two columns are equal. This is what I have for counting the rows where the 4 columns equal "something" but I can't figure out how to add the last part:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A100,"something",B2:B100,"something",C2:C100,"something",D2:D100,"something", [...])
```

Now I need to add another statement within this `COUNTIFS` at the `[...]` that says something like "exclude all rows where value in J is equal to value in K", but I can't seem to figure out how to do that WITHIN the `COUNTIFS` statement.

Comment: I generally do this is two steps.  First, I create a new column that does the comparison.  as in  if (A1 = B1, 1,0)   Then I would use either sum(...) or countif(...) to count the number of times A1 is equal to B1.  I hardly ever use COUNTIFS as it hasn't always given me the results I've needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have to move to a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff).

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100="something")*(B2:B100="something")*(C2:C100="something")*(D2:D100="something")*(J2:J100<>K2:K100))
```

Avoid full column references in SUMPRODUCT due to the cyclic nature of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Array function for this.

```
={sum((A1:A1000 = 'Something')*(BB:B1000 = 'Something')*(C1:C1000 = 'Something')*(D1:D1000 = 'Something')*(J1:J1000 = K1=K1000))}
```

for entering an array function, you need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter

More info at [Excel Array Functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)